# CollapsingToolbarLayout leaving empty space below Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, coordinator-layout

I'm having this strange issue with CoordinatorLayout and RecyclerView.

As you can see in the image, the RecyclerView is leaving an empty blank space below it with the **exact same height** as declared for CollapsingToolbarLayout's minHeight attribute.

If I don't declare this attribute, the **linear_navigation** LinearLayout won't remain pinned to the top of the screen (and that's the desired behaviour).

I'm I missing something? Here's the layout's code and some screenshots.

```html
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_header_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_welcome"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewComfortaaBold
                    android:id="@+id/text_username"
                    style="@style/TextViewTW.Title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_size_normal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Juancho"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_settings"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_settings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white" />

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_user"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_radious"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_radious"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_size_normal"
                        android:src="@drawable/madrid_01"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/karma_aqua_blue"
                        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/view_size_tiny" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_posts"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_size_normal">

                    <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewLatoRegular
                        style="@style/TextViewTW"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/profile_posts_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

                    <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewLatoRegular
                        android:id="@+id/text_posts_count"
                        style="@style/TextViewTW"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                        tools:text="1456" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/separator_height"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    android:background="@color/dark_grey" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_friends"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_size_normal">

                    <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewLatoRegular
                        style="@style/TextViewTW"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/profile_friends_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

                    <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewLatoRegular
                        android:id="@+id/text_friends_count"
                        style="@style/TextViewTW"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                        tools:text="1" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/separator_height"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    android:background="@color/dark_grey" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_reviews"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_size_normal">

                    <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewLatoRegular
                        style="@style/TextViewTW"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/profile_reviews_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

                    <com.tourwhiz.pro.widgets.TextViewLatoRegular
                        android:id="@+id/text_reviews_count"
                        style="@style/TextViewTW"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                        tools:text="12" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_post" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: The blank bottom space is the problem]

Comment: If my answer is useful for you .Could you accept and upvote it ?@MiguelS

Comment: @MiguelS, how did you use the CollapsingToolbarLayout without a Toolbar? I am tried removing the toolbar but my layout leaves an empty black space where the toolbar is supposed to be. :(

Comment: @Miguels I saw you are using **app:layout_collapseMode="pin"** with Linear Layout, how that is working for you ?? I'm in same issue and using **ToolBar instead of LinearLayout** and bottom white space is same size as ToolBar size. Any observation you can add if remember !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround for my situation. I don't know exactly why it works, but it does. If somebody knows why this is working, or even better, why is it happening, please answer the question and I will be happy to accept the answer as correct.

The workaround is placing an empty gone view below the RecyclerView. It's working for me!

```
                   ...
               </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_posts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_post" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in your `RecyclerView` .

Remove `android:layout_gravity="bottom` .

Comment: Sorry man, this has nothing to do with my problem. I've tried anyways and that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The fix which is suggested in the answer by **@KeLiuYue** may work.

Also(if the above fix fails) there is the problem in many cases with the **Design's library**.So there may be cases when this fix might not work since the layouts whose designs are less than the screen height cause white spaces, some mysterious behaviors in collapsing or unfolding the `<CollapsingToolbarLayout>`. There are still bugs that persists with this library and hopefully the glitch might be fixed someday.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion too .

Comment: I've read about problems with the design library, but mine's pretty concise: the space in the bottom is always equals to the minHeight declared for the CollapsingToolbarLayout.